# Was Gene Wolfe the first to use the animal-plant-mineral naming convention

Tags: history-of, names, gene-wolfe

In *The Book of the Long Sun*, Gene Wolfe uses the convention that male characters are named for animals or things derived from animals, female characters are named for plants or things derived from plants, and sentient machines are named for minerals.

Was he the first to use that naming convention?

Comment: I believe the standard phrase is "animal, vegetable, or mineral."

Comment: @Adamant, that's the typical phrase, but I think the characters in the books said, "animal, plant, mineral", or possibly ". . . inorganic".